regression discontinuity in Stata
I am working on a regression discontinuity design (RDD) analysis using both rdrobust and reg commands in Stata. However, I'm encountering a discrepancy in the results when estimating the Average Treatment Effect (ATE).

Using rdrobust: The ATE is estimated to be 0.02478.

Using reg: The ATE is estimated to be 0.0261112.


Both regressions use the same data, kernel type (uniform), bandwidth (60), and include the same covariates (session2 session3 session4). Given that these settings are identical, I would expect the ATE estimates to be very close, but they are not.
Here is the code I am using:
rdrobust command rdrobust Y R , p(1) kernel(uniform) h(60) covs (session2 session3 session4)
reg command reg Y i.treated##c.R session2 session3 session4 if R<=60 & R>=-60
but the result is different
